# How can I make this work (Basic mysqli and PHP)?

Tags: php, mysqli

Below is my code:

```
      $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM products');
      if($result === FALSE){
        die(mysql_error());
      }

      if($result){

        while($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
            if ($obj->typeOf === 'single')
            {   
                $forPack = $mysqli->query('SELECT id FROM products WHERE typeOf = 12-pack AND product_name = '.$obj->product_name);
                $forPound = $mysqli->query('SELECT id FROM products WHERE typeOf = 50-pound AND product_name = '.$obj->product_name);

                echo '<div class="large-3 columns">';
                echo '<p><h3>'.$obj->product_name.'</h3></p>';
                echo '<img src="images/products/'.$obj->product_img_name.'"/>';
                echo '<p><strong>Price (Per Unit)</strong>: '.$currency.$obj->price.'</p>';
                echo '<p><a href="update-cart.php?action=add&id='.$obj->id.'"><input type="submit" value="Add Single" style="clear:both; background: #0078A0; border: none; color: #fff; font-size: 1em; padding: 10px;" /></a></p>';
                echo '<p><a href="update-cart.php?action=add&id='.$forPack.'"><input type="submit" value="Add 12-pack" style="clear:both; background: #0078A0; border: none; color: #fff; font-size: 1em; padding: 10px;" /></a></p>';
                echo '<p><a href="update-cart.php?action=add&id='.$forPound.'"><input type="submit" value="Add 50 pound" style="clear:both; background: #0078A0; border: none; color: #fff; font-size: 1em; padding: 10px;" /></a></p>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
```

The area I'm having trouble with is $forPack and $forPound. In my table of products there are generally three products. The product, the product in a 12-pack, and the product in a 50-lb thing. Everything works fine for the first one of the three update-cart.php calls. The one that says $obj->id, but I can't seem to get the $forPack or $forPound to work. They have the exact same product name, just different 'typeOf' on the server. When I query to select the ID, isn't it just returning a number? What EXACTLY is being returned here?

I just need the program to look in the products table for the product that has the same exact name, but a different type. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know. I am a complete beginner to SQL and PHP, so I'm sure it's a dumb mistake.

Comment: You're getting a recordset back from the database when you call `query`; you need to iterate through that to get the value that you're looking for.

Comment: A couple of other things - you can get both values in the same query; you can possibly do `SELECT if, typeOf FROM products WHERE typeOf IN ('12-pack', '50-pound')`, though then your recordset will have two rows in it, and you'll need to process it accordingly. Also note that if you're looking for a text value (`12-pack`), you need to wrap it in quotes, otherwise MySQL will assume it's a column name.

Comment: A recordset like an array or what? How would I iterate through this recordset? I've been trying this for about an hour now and I don't know what the hell I'm doing. Why would I have anything to iterate through if I'm selecting a unique id? I don't understand.

Comment: Have a look at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php It's got examples of how to query a database, and how you can then process the results. When you run a SELECT, you will either get a boolean false (which tells you the query has failed), or a recordset. It might be a recordset with one entry in it, but it'll still be a recordset - the database doesn't care that there's just a single value being returned.

Comment: Would the suggestion ___A few hours with the SQL manual___ be a good idea

Comment: I wish I had time for that, but right now, I made a big mistake of saying I can do a website beyond my capabilities so I need all of the time I can. After this site is done, I will definitely take some courses on backend development so I am never in as big of a crunch as I am now. I admit this was a big mistake, but I'll be damned if I don't give it my best shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 different things going on here:

1. Typos (not including quotes where needed)
2. Your resultset is currently an array, not a single value.  Try this:

   `$forPack = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE typeOf = '12-pack' AND product_name = '" . $obj->product_name . "'")->fetch_row()[0];`

   `$forPound = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE typeOf = '50-pound' AND product_name = '" . $obj->product_name . "'")->fetch_row()[0];`

Not sure why site is refusing to use the code block.  At any rate, note that your SQL is now using double quotes for the whole statement so you can use single quotes inside.  Additionally, single quotes are around the `typeOf` value and the `$obj->product_name`.  When building your SQL strings, it's a good idea to echo them first so you can see they were built properly.  To do this, I'd do something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM products WHERE typeOf = '12-pack' AND product_name = '" . $obj->product_name . "'";
echo $sql;
$forPack = $mysqli->query($sql)->fetch_row()[0];
```